# 2 dimensional list in Python, trying to move data from one list to another

Tags: python, list

I am stuck on a 2D list data transfer problem. In a nutshell, I have 2D list like this:

```
listA = [['Green', 11455519, 23, 11661206], ['Blue', 7000039, 42, 6690388]]
```

It has 20 or more rows that follow the same pattern, I just plucked out two. I want to transfer the data over to a new list, where, as an example, I would just select some of the columns, so that it would look like this:

```
listB = [['Green', 23 ], ['Blue', 42]]
```

Instead I am getting this:

```
listB = [['Green', 23 ,'Blue', 42],[]]
```

i.e. all elements are falling into only the first row. So for my actual example, that means all the elements piled in, in that pattern and fashion, in the first row, and then 20 [] empty rows afterwards in that listB. I am using append and nested for statements to no avail.

Can I please ask for some help?

Thanks!

J

---

Hello everyone Thank you for all the answers! Totally newbie here, but really want to learn. The problem is actually a lot more layered than this. But as you say, I will not learn unless I dig. Also, in the class I am in we are just using basics, like nested for statements, so no pandas. And for this assignment, to hand in, we cannot import anything, only csv to work with csv files. We cannot use max() nor min() nor sort() nor sorted().

So there is a big csv file, with countries and populations and years. Countries down the left column, years along the first row, and populations. Like 20 countries, 18 columns of years.

I have imported that csv file into my IDE, to a 2D list. Then I applied calculations to it to have min population, max population and pop change. This data i now want to save into a new 2D list. THIS IS WHERE I get stuck.

```py
>my own min() and max() defs.
    def maxValue(listValues):
       maximum = 0
       for counter in listValues:
           if counter > maximum:
               maximum = counter
       return maximum 

    def minValue(listValues):
        minimum = listValues[0]
        for counter in listValues:
            if counter < minimum:
               minimum = counter
        return minimum


>convert the data in the 2D list into integers
    for row in range(0, len(befolkning)):
        for column in range(1,len(befolkning[row])):
            befolkning[row][column] = int(befolkning[row][column]) 


>go through data set, make calculations, and then try to append >them to a new listAnalyzed, which would have only 4 columns, 
>with country, maxpop, minpop, popchange. 
    listAnalyzed = []
    for row in befolkning[1:]:
        for colum in row:
            maxPop = maxValue(row[1:])
            minPop = minValue(row[1:])         
            chgPop = ((row[18] - row[1]) / row[1]) * 100
        
        listAnalyzed.append(row[0])
        listAnalyzed.append(maxPop)
        listAnalyzed.append(minPop)
        listAnalyzed.append(chgPop)
    print(listAnalyzed)
```

But when I print listAnalyzed, I just get all the data in a single 1D list. I tried different combos, sometimes getting 18 rows in a 2D list (great) but all the data in the first row only. The more I messed with the code, the worst it got. So i stopped before it just got me more confused.

what I need is a 2D list with 18 rows, each row with 4 columns (country, max, min,change). How do I do it?

Thank you! Really chugging here :(

Comment: Can you add your code to the question?

Comment: What I see you want is to know what's wrong with your code. You have to share it first. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: "so that it would look like this:...Instead I am getting this..." Please show the code that produces this result. I can show you how I would solve the problem, but that won't help you understand what mistake you made in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

```
listA = [['Green', 11455519, 23, 11661206], ['Blue', 7000039, 42, 6690388]]
[x[0:4:2] for x in listA]
```

Output

```
Out[5]: [['Green', 23], ['Blue', 42]]
```

Comment: An explanation of what you've done is much appreciated

Comment: this is called list comprehension...and we are accessing the require elements with a:b:c this means give the values from a to b but not all only the every cth element....

Comment: I mean in your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

With a list comprehension, you can select for each row the items you want in your new list. In this example I select the items ẁith indices `0` and `2`:

```
listB = [[x[0],x[2]] for x in listA]

print(listB)
```

Output:

```
[['Green', 23], ['Blue', 42]]
```

Comment: Hi! I edited the original question, thank you for your help!

Comment: Hello! I think you should create a new question for this extension as a question should only have one topic. Otherwise, the Q&A format would get very messy. A new question will also draw more attention meaning it is more likely to be solved. Before you post it directly as new question you should consider adding a small table of input data. This helps people understand your problem. Also, if your original question was answered you should consider to accept one of the answers to signal that the question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

If the list is a very long one it's better to use a library that uses for data manipulation like [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) for better performance.

Pandas come with [`df.to_numpy()` or `df.values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html?highlight=values#pandas.DataFrame.values) function to convert the data frame to a [`numpy.ndarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html#numpy-ndarray) and [`tolist()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html#pandas.Series.tolist) function can be used to convert the resultant array into a list.

```
import pandas as pd


listA = [['Green', 11455519, 23, 11661206], ['Blue', 7000039, 42, 6690388]]

df = pd.DataFrame(listA)
print(df)

# output
#       0         1   2         3
# 0  Green  11455519  23  11661206
# 1   Blue   7000039  42   6690388

print(df[[0, 2]].values.tolist())
# output
# [['Green', 23], ['Blue', 42]]
```